# Around what year did games go widescreen?

Tags: hardware, monitor, gaming-history

I am building a WinXP box to play games I have trouble with on Win10, and I am thinking of placing a 4:3 screen on it, as I didn't think games really supported widescreen until probably well after WinXP was legacy...but I was wondering around what year would I start seeing some or most games going widescreen? Or in another way, when did widescreen monitors become common on new computers?

I am not sure if a widescreen monitor would display the 4:3 output in a box (for games that did not scale or stretch to widescreen)...but I think that 4:3 games look much better when framed in a monitor of the same shape.

Comment: I dont think there was one set moment in time where every developer started making widescreen games but I do know for sure than the Original most wanted from 2005 is 4:3 and it doesn't scale well to wide screen. Actually it doesn't at all and you have to use separate app to stretch the game to fit your screen.

Comment: Will be far cheaper and safer to just install VirtualBox

Comment: To the people who are close voting because they think this is an "Identify This Game" question, It's not. This is a gaming history question.

Comment: @Nzall Close enough

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer the difference is that gaming history questions AFAIK are fully accepted on this site, while indentification questions without tangible assets are not.

Comment: @Nzall Gaming history questions run a *very* fine line.  Seeing it as game identification is to be expected in most cases, really.  Just portraying this as gaming history doesn't automatically make it on-topic, either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about basic computing history, not anything specific to gaming.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: @OrangeDog I have tried VBox and while it works for some games, I get weird behavior in others, such as ludicrously fast aspects of the game which make unplayable. If I reduce CPU speed (using VBox) it becomes a little better but audio stutters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on http://www.wsgf.org/mgl, widescreen support in some way, be it through external software, manually changing ini settings, changing registry entries, a command line flag or completely native, was in most games around 2000. Fully native support was pretty much standard around 2006.

Comment: Interesting. I guess that is mainly for 3d games? I have a few adventure games that don't scale at all well to fullscreen.

Comment: @aaa90210 Check the link I posted. It has almost 30 pages of games starting from 1984.

Comment: oh yes the link was excellent, I was just guessing mainly that the 3d games would be easiest to make widescreen than those with pre-rendered 2d backgrounds. Thanks.

Comment: @aaa90210 It honestly depends on the game. Many 2D games are simply a sliding viewport on a map, and making those widescreen frequently is just increasing the width of the viewport and maybe resolving some bugs. 3D games are actually somewhat trickier because you then could get into problems with HUD design (what parts of the hud do we make wider?), FoV (we need to adjust gun models so they don't end halfway), balance (widescreen means more peripheral vision) and even gameplay and atmosphere (some games rely on certain objects not being visible at the same time).